# Confusion with the output of %r/..../option.to_s

Tags: ruby

I was playing to see how `Regex#to_s` disable options with the pattern `%r/../`. But getting confused with the output of such `Regex#to_s` :

```
irb(main):005:0> %r/ab+c/x.to_s
=> "(?x-mi:ab+c)"   #why here -m option has been disabled?

irb(main):006:0> %r/ab+c/i.to_s
=> "(?i-mx:ab+c)"   #why here -m option has been disabled?

irb(main):007:0> %r/ab+c/m.to_s
=> "(?m-ix:ab+c)"   #why here -i option has been disabled?

irb(main):008:0> %r/ab+c/o.to_s
=> "(?-mix:ab+c)"   #why here o option not get into the (...) as the above?

irb(main):009:0> %r/ab+c/.to_s
=> "(?-mix:ab+c)"   #why always m,i,x option get into the (...) as the above?
```

Could anyone help me here to understand the logic on which based the option are getting on/off?

How do the `Regex#hash` and `Regex#quote` methods work in Ruby 1.9.3 (any small code to understand the same)?

Comment: Can anyone help me by answering why not `o` and why always `i,m,x` except `o`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your understanding is inverted; the options on the left of the dash are on, while the options to the right of the dash are off.

```
/ab+c/x => "x-mi"
/ab+c/i => "i-mx"
/ab+c/m => "m-ix"
```

Each of the three options appears in each regex string, but their presence to the left or right of the dash indicates whether the option is on or off.

Regarding your second question, `Regexp#hash` is simply a method that generates the same Fixnum for a given Regexp. This allows you to compare two different Regexp options for effective equality. See [Object#hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-hash) for more details.

Comment: Yes, That I would like to see by a possibly a small code to see the `Regex#hash` and `Regex#quote`. you give me a link for `string#hash` :)

Comment: why not the case for `o`? why by default always `m,x,i` not `o`?

Comment: Regexp#hash's implementation is available straight from the doc. It's implemented in C. The reason `o` doesn't show up in the regexp is because of what it does; it makes no sense for `o` to be in a serialized regexp string. Interpolations would simply be performed before serializing the regexp.

Comment: I didn't get your point the `serialization`. Can you bit demonstrate that?

Comment: And how `hash#quote` works, I just would like to see how to use it in a statement? I tried the below,but nothing get as a output - `quote("%r/cat/m")` .